Chicken Waterer
I’m trying to use a rain barrel to create a cycling water system for my chickens.  I’m going to open a 3 in PVC pipe for them to drink out of.  I want to run the system from a 50 gal rain barrel which already has a spigot to the pvc pipe for the chickens and back into the rain barrel.
I have the rain barrel, the spigot, can create a return hole for the water, and a pond pump.    What I can’t seem to find are parts to go from a 3 in pvc pipe to something I can attach to the rain barrel on both ends to complete the circuit.  The smallest reducers I can find are 1 1/2 in.
Am I approaching this wrong?  Any suggestions for a newbie ? (my only plumbing experience is installing a water heater).

Have you got a sump for the pump?

You need a number of reducers in line.
1/2 inch to 3/4, 3/4 to 1 inch, 1 to 1.5 inch, etc.
Short pipe nipples maybe, depending on reducers.
For chickens/animals/livestock I would prefer to drain the excess water on the ground than returning it, so fill up the 3 inch pipe and what is not used, open a drain on the end/dump it.
Saving money for the pump and power, reducing stuff that can break and reduce disease.
I am assuming a 3 inch pipe with the top cut off/holes in it.
